# ¿Porque el comando $git push carga eternamente?

Tags: git, github, cmd

A ver clone mi proyecto *PyDEX* de Github, realice algunos cambios use los comandos correspondientes

```
$git add .
$git commit -m "1.0"
```

los dos comando me funcionaron perfectamente no hubo ningún error, pero cuando coloco el `$git push` literal carga eternamente llevo 4 horas esperando y no termina. No se que sea, de hecho use Git en otra computadora y me funciona perfecto entonces no se realmente que pase.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si hago el comando "$git status" sale lo siguiente:

```
    $ git status
    On branch main
    Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit.
      (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Bueno espero que esa ultima información ayude de algo, gracias a quien pueda ayudar :3

Comment: No es que cargue infinitamente, lo más seguro es que te habrá una ventana de login para iniciar sesión y hacer el push, revisa si está oculta la ventana. La primera opción es una ventana con el logo de github, si la cierras te parece otra muy sencilla tipo promt.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, pues no me aparece ninguna ventana a simple vista pero investigare gracias :3

Comment: Revise el administrador de tareas y sale  un programa "git-credential-manager-core.exe"  creo que tiene algo que ver

Comment: Podria ser esto mismo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68057254/after-git-push-u-origin-main-command-git-bash-is-not-requesting-any-authentic

Comment: Si finalice la tarea y sale una ventana llamada "OpenSSH", que me pide un username para github pongo mi nombre de usuario de github no?

Comment: Listo lo logre arreglar muchas gracias, me responderé a mi mismo por si alguien necesita ayuda con eso.

Comment: De cualquier forma te recomendaría que investigaras sobre cómo usar las llaves ssh y pgp para Github